# ¿ Cómo sumar los valores de una matriz con python?

Tags: python, array, pandas

En una matriz de números positivos y negativos (ganancias y gastos), Cómo puedo sumar los números negativos y los positivos por separado en todas las columnas en python?

```
nueva_fila =[]
for j in range(columnas):
    suma = sum([fila[j] for fila in arr])
    nueva_fila.append(suma)

print(nueva_fila)
```

este código suma pero la columna completa?

[image: parte del array con la suma de todos los valores de cada columna]

Comment: Cuál es el problema con tu código??

Comment: Quiero que por una parte me sume solo los valores positivos y por otra los negativos , para cada columna! ya que este código me suma toda la columna positivos y negativos juntos!

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Tu matriz la puedes pasar a un arreglo de `numpy` o a un dataframe de `pandas` y filtrar los valores

### Con numpy:

Ejemplo con `numpy` usando una matriz simple (Puedes substituirla con tu matriz)

```
import numpy as np

matriz = [[1 , -1, 1],[-1, 1, 1],[-1, -1, 1]]
np_matriz = np.array(matriz)
resultado = ((np_matriz<0)*np_matriz).sum(0)
```

Explicación:

Al pasar la matriz a numpy array queda así

```
np_matriz = array([[ 1, -1, 1],
                  [-1,  1, 1],
                  [-1, -1, 1]])
```

Filtramos todos los valores negativos usando `np_matriz < 0` y nos genera una matriz de  booleanos donde los elementos que cumplen con la condición (En este caso que sean menor a 0) se indican con `True` y los que no cumplan con `False`

```
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

Multiplicamos por la matriz original para que en lugar de tener `True` y `False` tengamos los valores numéricos de cada "celda" `(np_matriz < 0)*np_matriz` y nos queda así:

```
array([[ 0, -1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0]])
```

Luego pedimos que haga la suma con `sum()` y la dirección de la suma es vertical (Columna) es decir, utilizamos el eje (Axis) `0` con la siguiente instrucción `((np_matriz < 0)*np_matriz).sum(0)` y nos queda así:

```
array([-2, -2,  0])
```

Eso ya es el resultado por columna, para obtener los números positivos solo tienes que cambiar la condición del filtro es decir `((np_matriz >= 0)*np_matriz).sum(0)`

### Con dataframe:

Ejemplo con `pandas` usando una matriz simple (Puedes substituirla con tu matriz)

```
import pandas as pd

matriz = [[1 , -1, 1],[-1, 1, 1],[-1, -1, 1]]
df =pd.DataFrame(matriz)
resultado = df[df < 0].sum()
```

Explicación:

Al pasar la matriz a un dataframe queda así (Primera fila y primera columna son los índices de filas y columnas)

```
    0   1   2
0   1   -1  1
1   -1  1   1
2   -1  -1  1
```

Filtramos los valores negativos usando `df < 0` y nos genera un dataframe de booleanos

```
    0       1       2
0   False   True    False
1   True    False   False
2   True    True    False
```

Filtramos el dataframe original con el dataframe de booleanos `df[df < 0]` para que nos de un dataframe únicamente con los números negativos (Los que no cumplan con la condición se verán como NaN, del inglés Not a Number)

```
    0       1       2
0   NaN     -1.0    NaN
1   -1.0    NaN     NaN
2   -1.0    -1.0    NaN
```

Hacemos la suma con el método `sum()` de la siguiente forma `df[df < 0].sum()` y nos devuelve la suma por columnas

```
0   -2.0
1   -2.0
2    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Ten en cuenta que el resultado es una serie, cada índice representa una columna

Si deseas obtener la suma de valores positivos haces lo mismo pero cambiando la condición, es decir `df[df >= 0].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

espero poder ayudarte. Puedes modificar tu actual código de la siguiente forma.

```
nueva_fila =[]
for j in range(columnas):
    suma_positiva = sum([fila[j] for fila in arr if fila[j] >=0])
    suma_negativa = sum([fila[j] for fila in arr if fila[j] <=0])

    nueva_fila.append((suma_positiva, suma_negativa))

print(nueva_fila)
```

En este caso nueva fila seria una lista en donde cada elemento es una tupla, el primer elemento es la suma de los números positivos y el segundo elemento es la suma de los números negativos.

Recuerda que puedes acceder directamente a los valores de una lista iterando sobre ellas, en lugar de hacer:

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
    print(lista[i])
```

puedes usar:

```
for elemento in lista:
    (elemento)
```

Comment: muy poco eficiente volver a iterar. Lo mejor es iterar una sola vez

Comment: Puedes hacerlo iterando solo una vez, sin el uso de librerias externas? Quiero verlo @Christian

Comment: @M.K me refiero a iterar una sola vez para obtener los positivos y negativos. En total sería solo 2 veces (lo que representa filas y columnas)

Comment: creo que se refiere a que envez de hacer una list comprehesion hagas algo asi:

for j in columna:
   if columna[j] >0
      positivos.append()
   else:
      negativos.append()

de este modo harias una sola iteracion

Comment: excelente muchas gracias! fue de mucha utilidad sus respuestas!!